# Power Bi Plot dataset with x-axis dates

Tags: date, plot, powerbi

I am working with a dataset with which I am creating a dashboard. My dataset is very simple, a first column of [yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm], and a second column with many values.

I read in many threads and forum about the difficulty to plot dates on x-axis (including hours and minuts).

As reference I am using this dashboard built in PowerBi https://www.terna.it/it/sistema-elettrico/transparency-report/total-load .(Public data of Italian electric energy generation)

This is exactly the outcome I would like to obtain, but by now I cannot display the hours and minuts. I used their data to reproduce the dashboard.

I tried to switch from a "dates" x-axis to a "text" x-axis, but the result is not the same, and furthermore the plot does not occupy the whole page but I have to move to the right.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5MTz.png)

I really cannot understand how the linked dashboard was built.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem is that you have been using `Date Hierarchy` on the x-Axis you instead of `Date` only.

[image]

[image]